# How to add JavaFX-Project-Wizzard to Eclipse 4.9 with e(fx)clipse?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I am trying to create default JavaFX-projects in Eclipse Photon and therefore I wanted to use the plugin `e(fx)clipse` which I downloaded from the Marketplace (Eclipse Menubar > Help > Eclipse Marketplace).

After a restart of Eclipse I still can not find the option in the "New"-wizard to create a default JavaFX-project.

Did I forget something in the configs?

[image: e(fx)clipse-installation via marketplace]

[image: available wizards]

Answer (score 0):

I just update the entry to the latest which is 3.4.1

Comment: thanks, I uninstalled e(fx)clipse and installed e(fx)clipse 3.4.1 from the marketplace, but I still do not see the wizard for JavaFX projects in eclipse?